# как происходит маршрутизация в роутере?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, lan

Всем привет, не могу найти информацию, как работает маршрутизация в роутере.
Как роутер понимает, где искать ip адрес, внутри локальной сети или вне. Например адрес роутера 192.168.1.1 и приходит пакет с адресом 192.168.1.10, по ARP этот адрес роутер не находит. Будет ли роутер перенаправлять пакет на провайдера? И наоборот если запрос идет на внешний IP ищет ли он его внутри локальной сети?

UPD: Изучив дополнительно я понял следующее.
При формировании пакета я смотрю целевое устройство находится в моей подсети или нет.
1.Если в моей я по ARP нахожу его mac-адрес и отправляю на этот mac (В таком случае я подозреваю домашний роутер сработает в режиме коммутатора).
2. Если сеть любая другая, я указываю ip адресата и mac маршрутизатора(роутера). Роутер смотрит в таблицы маршрутизации, если есть такая подсеть, то отправляет туда пакет, если нет, сбрасывает на дефолтный порт(который ведет обычно к провайдеру). Остался только вопрос будет ли он на провайдера перекидывать серые ip формата 10.х.х.х, 192.168.х.х и т.д.?

Comment: Вот хорошие видео - https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtPJ9lKvJ4oiNMvYbOzCmWy6cRzYAh9B1

Comment: спасибо, обязательно изучу

Comment: @Tsyklop Видео уроки по OSI и TCP\IP ? в 21 веке читать вообще не принято?
АлександрРодин любой "учебник по TCP \ IP" прекрасно объясняет все принципы маршрутизации
(текст в кавычках можно вбить в поисковик и первыми строками будут учебники)
Автору вопроса советую учится читать и делать это на англицком, нормальную документацию по сложным вещам можно добыть только так.

Comment: алгоритм маршрутизации примитивен до безобразия: цикл по всем зарегистрированным машрутам; для каждого маршрута: если он подходит, отправляем пакет по этому маршруту и прекращаем цикл; конец цикла; если маршрут не был найден, отправляем пакет по умолчальному маршруту.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Мне проще видео посмотреть, чем искать книгу. + не совсем удобно читать с монитора или телефона. Это лично мое мнение. Свое можете оставить при себе. Мне оно не нужно.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я прочитал книгу, но когда сразу получаешь много информации сложно ее систематизировать и все запомнить. Разве не для этого нужен форум, чтобы можно было спросить, когда что то не понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предуведомление: написанное ниже относится только к [статической маршрутизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и, конечно, не претендует на покрытие всех возможных вариантов и нюансов конфигурации сетевой подсистемы.

---

в общем случае алгоритм маршрутизации примитивен до безобразия:

1. выбираем маршрут:

   - цикл по всем зарегистрированным машрутам

     - если маршрут подходит, выбираем его и прекращаем цикл
   - конец цикла
   - если подходящий маршрут не был найден, используем маршрут по умолчанию
2. выбираем способ отправки:

   как именно будет отправлен пакет по маршруту, зависит от его свойств (они устанавливаются при создании маршрута):

   - локальный маршрут. пакет даже не покидает пределов компьютера
   - внешний маршрут:

     - маршрут со шлюзом: пакет будет отправлен по ip-адресу этого шлюза
     - маршрут без шлюза: пакет будет отправлен непосредственно по указанному ip-адресу

да, для ряда типов сетевых интерфейсов (ethernet, wifi и т.п.) в случае выбора внешнего маршрута по целевому ip-адресу дополнительно определяется mac-адрес целевого устройства — при помощи [протокола arp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP). но это уже не к маршрутизации относится.

---

> Остался только вопрос будет ли он на провайдера перекидывать серые ip формата 10.х.х.х, 192.168.х.х и т.д.?

смотри выше алгоритм: если нет подходящего зарегистрированного маршрута — будет выбран маршрут по умолчанию. цвет/запах/тактильные свойства ip-адресов в данном случае не оказывают влияния на принимаемое решение.

---

доп. информация «для любознательных».

маршруты создаются как непосредственно, соответствующими командами, так и опосредованно, при добавлении ip-адреса (и «сетевой маски») к сетевому интерфейсу.

в операционной системе *gnu/linux* может существовать произвольное количество таблиц маршрутизации. по умолчанию их три (`rule` можно сокраать до `ru`):

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

при поиске подходящего маршрута таблицы маршрутизации просматриваются последовательно, по возрастанию их номеров.

просмотреть содержимое конкретной таблицы:

```
$ ip route show table имя.таблицы
```

например (`route` можно сократить до `r`, `show` — до `sh`, `table` — до `t`):

```
$ ip r sh t local
```

содержимое всех таблиц:

```
$ ip r sh t all
```